Multiple msixupload files for uwp with packaging project
I am trying to package a UWP application with a desktop extension as full trust process. For this, I have to use a separate packaging application for creating msixupload for store distribution and appxbundle for side loading.
My problem is that when I try to build using msbuild,

Multiple msixupload files are being built- One for uwp and one for the entire package. I want only one to be built for the entire package.

I want the name of the package to be of the UWP project to maintain consistency with what we had earlier.


I have removed all appx bundle related properties from vcxproj of UWP file except the package manifest file.
I tried setting  Appxbundle property as Never in the UWP vcxproj as well.

App Package Upload File can contain multiple app packages. you can generate single msixupload file after associating with the store in the windows application package project.

App Package Upload File can contain multiple app packages.
Add project references to UWP application and desktop extension in Windows Application Package Project, then you can generate single msixupload file after associating with the store in the Windows Application Package Project.
Right click the Windows Application Package Project, select Publish.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/package/packaging-uwp-apps#create-your-app-package-upload-file-using-visual-studio
